# Where to find supported WebAPIs in each browser

Tags: javascript

Short summary: Where can I find a list of which WebAPIs are supported by the different browsers ? WebAPIs link -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API. Only some functionality seems to work from the APIs and some doesnt seem to work at all (Ive seen the icons on the left side of each property that says its deprecated or not, but ive tried properties that also doesnt have any special mention about deprecation or not being standardized).

Longer explaination:
Im working with different WebAPIs just for experimentation and i was working with Navigator and NetworkInformation previously, but a lot of the properties in Navigator does not seem to work even though some of them should work according to MDN. When trying NetworkInformation.connection to get information I got a javascript error in google chrome saying that it didnt recognize something called "NetworkInformation".

According to caniuse.com the Navigator.battery property should work but it doesnt display anything except "undefined" when i use this simple code:

```
var battery = navigator.battery;
console.log(battery.charging);
```

Comment: And did you read the part about `navigator.battery` being replaced by `navigator.getBattery()`

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=battery

Comment: No, i didnt read that, i did however read the doc on MDN and i thought they would be updated enough to provide that information with a warning message..i do now see that the compatibility table shows the property as not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Battery Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getBattery) used to have a property named `navigator.battery`, this is only partially supported in Firefox.

The Battery Manager now uses a method that returns a promise to get battery information

```
navigator.getBattery().then(function(batteryData) {

    // supported properties

    batteryData.charging
    batteryData.chargingTime
    batteryData.dischargingTime
    batteryData.level
    batteryData.onchargingchange
    batteryData.onchargingtimechange
    batteryData.ondischargingtimechange
    batteryData.onlevelchange
});
```

The [Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API) is **only** supported in Firefox, there's a table at the bottom of the MDN pages for the API's that shows support.

Comment: I guess i didnt read the whole page and missed the compatibility information. I will always check that out from now on. I do think its a little strange that the navigator.battery doc says that you would use navigator.battery and the BatteryManager doc says that you have to you getBattery..conflicting information, but i guess it isnt completely up to date.. thanks.